# Convert Cell reference to the Cell Name Not Value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to display the reference of cell based on condition that if the cell contains a value it should display that the cell has a value for example
If cell A1 has a value eg 12, then cell B1 should display “There is value in cell A1” else it should be blank
I have tried this this

```
=IF(A1="","","There is value in cell "&A1).
```

Does anyone know how I can change it to =There is value in cell A1
Instead of There is value in cell 12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this

> =IF(A1="","","There is value in cell "&ADDRESS(ROW(A1),COLUMN(A1),4))

Also if you don't have any issue with the volatility an easier formula would be

> =IF(A1="","","There is value in cell "&CELL("address",A1))

P.S You can additionally use one of the four values as the last parameter in the first formula.

[image]

Comment: This will return `There is value in cell $A$1`

Comment: @zipa If I understood the question correctly that's what the OP wants!

Comment: @ImranMalek thanks it worked but I have to use substitude to remove "$"

Comment: @JonWay If you decided to go with `ADDRESS()` just add `4` as argument and it will give you relative reference.

Answer (score 1):

Does this do the trick:

```
=IF(A1<>"","There is a value in cell "&CHAR(64+COLUMN(A1))&ROW(A1),"")
```

You can also use `ADDRESS()`:

```
=IF(A1<>"","There is a value in cell "&ADDRESS(ROW(A1),COLUMN(A1),4))
```

It takes row and column as arguments with optional argument for return type, that is set to relative in this example.

Comment: That'll only work up to column Z though - _There is a value in cell [1_ for column `AA`.  You could use `CELL("address",A1)`.

Comment: Edited with extension for those cases.